# How do you know if your data is displayed semantically correct as a table or something else?

Tags: css, semantic-markup

I have information from a database.  It is one row.  Now, it is old, and tables were used to display the data.  It works but is ugly and hard to maintain.  I'm "fixing" it.  But, I don't know if it is considered tabular or not.  It comes from database tables, but I don't know that what it means to be semantically correct in using a table for display.

I have several sections like this on a webpages.  They are all calls to the same database, different sets of data, sectioned off in the webpage.

For example, one set is a general set of information, lastname, firstname, middle, other stats...

Next section might be address, etc.

A while back when I did asp.net forms there was a list view, I think that was similar to what I need to create (I'm using just straight html and a scripting language, no controls).

*How should I be displaying the information to be semantically correct?*

edit:  It is one person that does not repeat.

edit:  A single record, but displayed on the same page, just various `SELECT` statements to get that data all on the same page.

Comment: Based on your description, it *sounds* like tabular data. Are you showing the same categories of information for multiple people at the same time?

Comment: No.  It is one person that does not repeat.

Comment: With just information about one person, I wouldn't use a table. There are multiple options at that point - you could, for example, look at a definition list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's tabular data (i.e. multiple records displayed underneath each other) then a `<table>` would probably be the best choice. If it's a view of a single record, maybe even aggregating data from multiple tables then the `<table>` shouldn't be your first choice.

**Tabular data:**

```
 --------------------------------
| ID | Name | Description | Date |  
 --------------------------------
| 01 | ...  | ...         | ...  |
| 02 | ...  | ...         | ...  |
```

**Not tabular data:**

```
ID:          ...
Name:        ...
Description: .................
             .................
             .....

Date:        ....
```

Comment: I don't know if it is tabular data.  That's my problem.  I guess I don't understand what tabular data is.

Comment: Do you know what I might search for to get a good CSS display for the latter?  All I see are CSS forms and layouts.  I have a layout for the page itself, but am kind of lost on the rest.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Have a look at Twitter Bootstrap or similar frameworks: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: "If it's a view of a single record [...]  then the <table> shouldn't be your first choice." Why not?  If you're performing a search on tabular data and only end up with 1 result, do you use different markup?  Why is it tabular data when you have 2 or more results, but not if you have only 1?  How many rows does it take to be tabular data?  If 2 rows is enough to qualify as tabular data, why is a collection of key/value pairs not tabular data?

Comment: @cimmanon I wrote "if it's a view of a single record", not "if the query for whatever reason returns only one record where there might be multiple results as well". Have a look at my examples and I'm sure you'll understand where I draw the line.